# Tell Mathematica to use symbolic expression

Tags: variable-definitions

I would like to achieve a function `sin` as in:

```
T=Sin[t];
sin[x_]:=T/.t->x;
```

But without this replacement rule. How can I tell *Mathematica* plug in the definition of the variable first before defining the function?

I want *Mathematica* to treat `T` *exactly* as if I used `Sin[t]`. How can I achieve that?

Comment: `T[t_] = Sin[t];` then `T[x]` evaluates to `Sin[x]`

Comment: I want to use `T` as if i copy pasted the expression `T` stands for. I dont want `T` to be another function

Comment: Use `T = Sin[t]; sin[t_] = T;` then `sin[x] ` evaluates to `Sin[x] `

Comment: I want to use `T` also in environments like `sin=Function[t,T]`

Comment: as if i copy pasted Sin[t] in there

Comment: Since `Function` has the attribute `HoldAll` you would need to use `sin = Function[t, Evaluate@T]`

Comment: And I want ice cream...

Comment: `Evaluate@T` does exactly what I had in mind thanks a lot!